# Android Bitmap usage Optimization

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, android-asynctask

I've been reading up on different ways to use bitmap each with there own pros and cons.

And so I have a question that hasn't really been answered in my search.  I have a massive memory leak in my application.  So I working through solving the problem, and I use several bitmaps.  One Bitmap in particular is used many times by different objects.  I call the bitmap image and draw text on it using a Canvas and then compress and save the image in a resolution that suits the device that is using it.

Currently I fetch the bitmap using BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources, ResourceID) each time I need to draw new text and create a updated version of the image.

Is there a better way to fetch the image?  Like is caching it somewhere: 1) Possible? 2) A better way to reference the same image many times compared to decoding it from the drawable folder?

Note: This process is done using AsyncTask, so depending on the device the image could technically be used accessed serval time all at once.  Not sure if that could cause a resource collision.

Thanks All, I didn't feel like code was needed for an answer but if it is needed I can add it.

Comment: http://square.github.io/picasso/ this is your best option for loading from the web. other wise just refer to your resouce id in the application itself dont try passing around the drawable

Comment: Note that Picasso can also load images from the resources/assets

Comment: although i personally use fresco, but picasso would be better for your use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for simple Caching for Bitmap in Android, The following implementation will cache in both memory and file. when it load it bitmap resource again(identified by image file name), it will try to search the memory and then file cache for the bitmap.

Usage:

imageLoader.DisplayImage("image_filename_in_resource_folder", imageView);

```
public class ImageLoader {
        final int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_thumbnail;
    private Context mContext;
    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    ExecutorService executorService;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }



    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    protected Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 150;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    Bitmap getBitmap(String imageFileName) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(imageFileName);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        try {
            Resources resource = mContext.getResources();
            int imageId = resource.getIdentifier(imageFileName, "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream is = resource.openRawResource(imageId);
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            IOUtils.copy(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (null != bitmap) {
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class for Memory Cache

```
public class MemoryCache {
    private HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> cache = new HashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();

    public Bitmap get(String id) {
        if (!cache.containsKey(id))
            return null;
        SoftReference<Bitmap> ref = cache.get(id);
        return ref.get();
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap) {
        cache.put(id, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(bitmap));
    }

    public void clear() {
        cache.clear();
    }
}
```

The class for File Cache

```
public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context) {
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "LazyList");
        else
            cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        if (!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public File getFile(String url) {
        //Identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution.
        String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());

        //Another possible solution, using cypto hashing functions like md5
        //String filename = md5(url);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear() {
        File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
        if (files == null)
            return;
        for (File f : files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```