# Draw a fixed size bitmap image on canvas

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, surfaceview

I am creating a card game, for this i have created a custom surface view, in which images are getting load. Since images are downloaded from internet, they are of different sizes and looks visually bad on screen. I want to achieve two things here.

1. Load images of fixed size or resize the images dynamically.
2. Draw images from bottom of screen in upward direction.

For 1st point i used CreateBitmap method but getting below exception.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1915060280 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 123MB until OOM error
```

To fixed the issue i thought of using Glide/Picasso based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823249/resize-image-to-full-width-and-fixed-height-with-picasso?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889735/resize-image-to-full-width-and-variable-height-with-picasso?noredirect=1&lq=1), but i found out that Glide/Picasso load images only on imageview, but i don't have any imageview, i only got a custom surfaceview inside a linearlayout.

For 2nd point i used rotation of image. Following is the code of that.

```
  public  void Render(Canvas paramCanvas)
    {

        try
        {
            // paramCanvas.DrawColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Blue);


            int i = 0;
            Down_Card_Gap = 0;
            foreach (Cards localcard in FaceDownDeck.ToList())
            {


                Bitmap localimage = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, localcard.GetImageId(context));  
                Bitmap rotatedimage = RotateBitmap(localimage, 180);
                paramCanvas.DrawBitmap(rotatedimage, (Screen_Center_X - Card_Width / 2)+Down_Card_Gap, (Screen_Height - Card_Height), null);
               //   paramCanvas.DrawBitmap(localimage, (Screen_Center_X - Card_Width / 2), (Screen_Center_Y - Card_Height), null);


                if (i++ == 7)
                { break; }
                if (Down_Card_Gap > 0)
                {
                    Down_Card_Gap += Card_Width / 2; 
                }
                else
                {
                    Down_Card_Gap -= Card_Width / 2;
                }
                Down_Card_Gap *= -1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap localimage, float angle)
    {
         Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.PostRotate(angle);
        matrix.PostScale(Card_Width, Card_Height);
        Bitmap resized= Bitmap.CreateBitmap(localimage, 0, 0, localimage.Width, localimage.Height, matrix, true);
        localimage.Recycle();
        return resized;
    }
```

I want to know if it is a right approach, or is there any better method achieve the functionality.

Comment: Your question is broadly, one question, one answer in SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Load images of fixed size or resize the images dynamically.

About the fixed size and resize, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37632770/8632294), find `decodeFile` method:

```
   protected Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try { 
            //decode image size 
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2. 
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 150;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) { 
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break; 
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            } 

            //decode with inSampleSize 
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } 
        return null; 
    }
```

You can see, it uses  `BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeBounds= true` to preload the bitmap, and scale the bitmap. Also you can refer to [official document](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap). Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29012075/8632294) to compress bitmap's quality.

Except from this, you also need consider the picture cache.[This talks about how to build an efficient memory cache for bitmaps.](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap)